# Problem Displaying Multiple Items From Same Column In One Row

Tags: t-sql

I have three tables, `DailyFieldRecord`, `AB953`,and `Lookup`. The `DailyFieldRecord` table contains `DailyFieldRecordID`.The `AB953` table contains `DailyFieldRecordID`,`GroupID`,`LookupID`, and `PersonID`. The `Lookup` table contains `GroupID`, `Description`, and `LookupID`. I'm trying to display the persons ethnicity, age, and gender in the same row based on each `DailyFieldRecordID` and `PersonID`. The problem I'm having is that the descriptions of ethnicity, age, and gender are in the same column in the lookup table. I've tried different ways, but am only able to get the correct information for one person. Any input would be helpful.

```
 DailyFieldRecord:      AB953:
DailyFieldRecordID     DailyFieldRecordID:  LookupID: GroupID: PersonID:
  1111                   1111                 1260     300       1
                         1111                 1262     200       1
                         1111                 1264     310       1
                         1111                 1258     300       2
                         1111                 1261     200       2
                         1111                 1265     310       2
Lookup:
GroupID:   Description: LookupID:
300          white         1260
300          latin         1258
200           17           1262
200           18           1261
310          male          1264
310          female        1265

Select ab.DailyFieldRecordID, lkp.Description as 
Ethinicity,lkp2.Description as Age, lkp3.Description as Gender, 
ab.PersonID
FROM DailyFieldRecord dfr
LEFT JOIN AB953 ab ON ab.DailyFieldRecordID=dfr.DailyFieldRecordID and 
ab.GroupID=300 and ab.PersonID=1
LEFT JOIN AB953 ab2 ON ab2.DailyFieldRecordID=dfr.DailyFieldRecordID and 
ab2.GroupID=200 and ab2.PersonID=1
LEFT JOIN AB953 ab3 ON ab3.DailyFieldRecordID=dfr.DailyFieldRecordID and 
ab3.GroupID=310 and ab3.PersonID=1
LEFT JOIN Lookup lkp ON lkp.LookupID=ab.ItemID 
LEFT JOIN Lookup lkp2 ON lkp2.LookupID=ab2.ItemID
LEFT JOIN Lookup lkp3 ON lkp3.LookupID=ab3.ItemID


Current output:
DailyFieldRecordID: Ethnicity: Age: Gender: PersonID:
1111                  white    17     male     1

Expected output:
DailyFieldRecordID: Ethnicity: Age: Gender: PersonID:
1111                  white    17     male     1
1111                  latin    18     female   2
```

Comment: You should be joining to `ab.PersonId`, not `1`, in each outer join after the first. The first one does not need to join on `PersonId`, it is the source of it..

Comment: your right thank you

Comment: I was wondering if there is an easier way of writing this in case I had to join more tables or constraints

Answer (score 0):

Though i must say, this is very bad DB design, Yet you are getting only first person ID coz you are using PersonID = 1 in the query. Please try below query removing PersonID = 1.

```
Select ab.DailyFieldRecordID
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN lkp.GroupID = 300 THEN lkp.Description) as Ethinicity
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN lkp.GroupID = 200 THEN lkp.Description) as Age
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN lkp.GroupID = 310 THEN lkp.Description) as Gender
      ,ab.PersonID
FROM DailyFieldRecord dfr
LEFT JOIN AB953 ab ON ab.DailyFieldRecordID=dfr.DailyFieldRecordID
LEFT JOIN Lookup lkp ON lkp.GroupID=ab.GroupID
GROUP BY ab.DailyFieldRecordID, ab.PersonID
```

Comment: It gives me 8 rows with every combination of ethnicity,age, and gender for both PersonID's if I remove the PersonID=1